# communication between 2 device using sms

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm looking for a way to communicate between two devices via SMS و try to send command via  SMS message from 5554 and receive SMS in 5556 , read command and execute command .

For example, he sent a message from 5554 contain "flash" to 5556 is that it gives a flash

note:5556 only receives from 5554 not all users.
this code send sms:

```
 SmsManager smsManager =     SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("Phone Number", null, "Message", null, null);
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

please help me:

Comment: And you expect us to write this code for you, right?

Comment: The mention of 5554 and 5556 make it seem like you are using emulator virtual devices.  You'll want to look into the documentation for the emulator and see if device-to-device simulated SMS is supported, or if you are going to have to write custom code for the dev machine to catch the output of one and push it back into the other.  At the very least, you'll probably want to do some "one sided" testing using the emulator console send/receive SMS capability to test one half of the system without having to worry about the other half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you able to send sms you probably able to make TCPIP connection.
Anyway all you need is create Android Service and handler which will listen for incoming SMSes.
Examples can be found :

1. [Android-SMS-Handler-Runnable-and-Service-new](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615430/Android-SMS-Handler-Runnable-and-Service-new)
2. [listening-for-outgoing-sms-or-send-sms-in-android/](http://katharnavas.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/listening-for-outgoing-sms-or-send-sms-in-android/)
3. [smspopup/SMSReceiverService.java](http://android-smspopup.googlecode.com/git-history/a3569600f8b01acdb99f50f9fbe29f1f6bd8d863/src/net/everythingandroid/smspopup/SMSReceiverService.java)
4. [create-an-application-auto-receiving-new-message-sms](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/create-an-application-auto-receiving-new-message-sms/)